# How to use domain exclusion DE via SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I have de created out of domain exclusion template and de contains only one field 'domain', and have inconsistent values like 'gmail.com' '@hotmail.com' '%yahoo%'.
I would like to use in SQL as suppression but could not find a way. I tried using in where clause
`Where emailaddress not in (select domain from exclusionde)`. I also tried using not exists. I tried `WHERE RIGHT(EmailAddress, LEN(EmailAddress) - CHARINDEX('@', EmailAddress)) not in (select domain from exclusionde)` but it's not working.

Any idea how to make it work via SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, I have DE1:

| SubscriberKey | EmailAddress |
| --- | --- |
| SubKey1 | john@gmail.com |
| SubKey2 | jane@hotmail.com |
| SubKey3 | josh@yahoo.com |
| SubKey4 | jack@test.com |

And excluded domain in the DE2:

| Domain |
| --- |
| @hotmail.com |
| yahoo.com |
| test.com |

To extract records in DE1 that uses any excluded email domain, you can try something like this:

```
SELECT
a.SubscriberKey,
a.EmailAddress
FROM DE1 AS a
INNER JOIN DE2 AS b
ON a.EmailAddress LIKE CONCAT('%', b.Domain)
```

It will result into DE3:

| SubscriberKey | EmailAddress |
| --- | --- |
| SubKey2 | jane@hotmail.com |
| SubKey3 | josh@yahoo.com |
| SubKey4 | jack@test.com |

Try yourself: https://dbfiddle.uk/hrM27Jtk

**Update**: to get records not using the excluded domain, you can use the DE result above (let's call DE3) with `left join`:

```
SELECT
a.SubscriberKey,
a.EmailAddress
FROM DE1 AS a
LEFT JOIN DE3 AS b
ON a.SubscriberKey = b.SubscriberKey
WHERE
b.SubscriberKey IS NULL
```